# laravel resource collection has blank output

Tags: laravel, api, collections, resources

I am trying to get a json output of a collection but all I am getting is a data [].

I have 2 tables.

> TABLE:Player ||
>   id |
>   name

and

> TABLE:FlightTime || id | vehicle | totaltime | player_id (foreign key)

I am trying to get all the flighttime entry for a particular player as a collection.

My FlightTime resource:

```
class FlightTime extends JsonResource
{
    public function toArray($request)
    {
        return [
            'vehicle' => $this->vehicle,
            'total-time' => $this->totaltime,
        ];
    }
}
```

And my FlightTimeCollection:

```
class FlightTimeCollection extends ResourceCollection
{
    public function toArray($request)
    {
        return [
           'data' => $this->collection,
           'test' => 'did this work',
       ];
    }
}
```

My api route is set as

```
Route::get('/v1/player/{name}/flights', 'PlayerController@showFlightbyName');
```

And I have this in my controller:

```
public function showFlightbyName($name)
    {
      $pid = Player::select('id')->where('name', $name)->first();

      return new FlightTimeCollection(FlightTime::where('player_id', $pid)->get());
    }
```

Now when I visit localhost/api/v1/player/Angel/flights, No error is thrown. But all I am getting is this.

```
{
    "data": [],
    "test": "did this work"
}
```

I just can't figure out what's going on here and what I did wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You should treat the `toArray()` method in your `FliightTimeCollection` the same way you treat it in `FlightTimeResource`. The collection will be automatically wrapped in `data => [stuff]'`.

So, like this:

```
class FlightTimeCollection extends ResourceCollection
{
    public function toArray($request)
    {
        return [
            'vehicle' => $this->vehicle,
            'another_field' => $this->field2,
            // ...
        ];
    }
}
```

Result of that would be

```
{
    "data": [
        {"vehicle": "some value", "another_field": "some value"},
        // ...
    ],
}
```

Comment: I tried as you suggested. Its throwing up an error.
`"Property [vehicle] does not exist on this collection instance."`

Answer (score 0):

I got it working. $pid is an obj and I needed to get the value out of $pid->id

```
public function showFlightbyName($name)
    {
      $pid = Player::select('id')->where('name', $name)->first();

      return new FlightTimeCollection(FlightTime::where('player_id', $pid->id)->get());
    }
```